# How to solve the trigonometric function equation to obtain the relationship between two angles in the equation?

Tags: equation-solving

In a triangle, the three inner angles are

```
α, β,γ
```

The trigonometric function relationship equation between the two inner angles is:

```
Cos[α]/(1 + Sin[α]) == Sin[2 β]/(1 + Cos[2 β])
```

You can obtain this by doing the following

```
TrigFactor[Apply[Subtract, Cos[α]/(1 + Sin[α]) == Sin[2 β]/(1 + Cos[2 β])]]
```

get the result:

```
Csc[π/4 + α/2] Sec[β] Sin[π/4 - α/2 - β]
```

In a triangle, the sum of the three internal angles is pi. How can we obtain the final relationship based on the known equation equation

The desired objective relationship is:

```
α + 2 β == π/2
```

Comment: fixed your Greek letters. It is better to post your code like the above to make it easier to read.  See [how-to-convert-greek-symbols-to-readable](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2667/how-to-convert-greek-symbols-to-readable-ones-when-posting-here-web-site-is-gon)  for link to a tool to do this.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you for the modification. The layout has become much clearer after the modification

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html).

```
Solve[Cos[α]/(1 + Sin[α]) == Sin[2 β]/(1 + Cos[2 β]), α, 
 Assumptions -> 0 <= {α, β} <= Pi && α + β < Pi]

(* {{α -> ConditionalExpression[1/2 (π - 4 β), β ∈ Reals && 0 < β < π/4]}} *)
```

$$\alpha + 2\beta = \frac\pi2 \quad \text{if} \quad \beta < \pi/4$$

Comment: ```Solve[{Cos[\[Alpha]]/(1 + Sin[\[Alpha]]) == 
   Sin[2 \[Beta]]/(1 + Cos[2 \[Beta]]), 0 <= \[Alpha] <= \[Pi], 
  0 <= \[Beta] <= \[Pi], \[Alpha] + \[Beta] < \[Pi]}, \[Alpha]]```

Comment: @csn899 What is the meaning of your comment?